# Transplant of haematopoietic stem cells, how do they get back into the bone marrow?

Tags: hematology, chemotherapy, bone-marrow

I read about [Hematopoietic stem cell transplantation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hematopoietic_stem_cell_transplantation?wprov=sfla1). However, under "Graft types", "Autologous", it states:

> The patient's own stored stem cells are then transfused into his/her bloodstream, where they replace destroyed tissue and resume the patient's normal blood-cell production.

What i do not understand from Wikipedia is, after the hematopoietic cells are extracted from the bone marrow, and then after chemotherapy or radiotherapy is applied, and then after the hematopoietic cells are reinjected into the blood stream, how do these hematopoietic cells make it back from the blood stream, into the bone marrow of the patient?

Thank you for your answer.

If not clear, it would be great to add this explanation to Wikipedia.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you read the more general article on [bone marrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_marrow)?